# What are the recommended WebDriver packages for Selenium

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

As of today (20th Jan 2019) there are 9 Nuget packages that match the broad description of "WebDriver for Chrome":

- `Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver` (955K downloads)
- `Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver` (4030K downloads)
- `WebDriver.ChromeDriver.win32` (289K downloads)
- `Chromium.ChromeDriver` (161M downloads)
- `AlexP.Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver` (1K downloads)
- `WebDriverChromeDriver` (95K downloads)
- `WebDriver.ChromeDriver` (100K downloads)
- `WebDriver.ChromeDriver.win32-2.36` (<1K downloads)
- `AsyncChromeDriver.SeleniumAdapter` (1K downloads)
- `AsyncChromeDriver` (8K downloads)

I suspect there will be slightly fewer such packages for other browsers (FFX, Safari, IE, etc.) But I'd still be unsurprised to see that there were multiple drivers.

How do I workout which one I should be using?

- None of them appear to be published by SeleniumHQ.
- `Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver` has the most downloads.
- `Chromium.ChromeDriver` appears to be published by the Chrome team.
- `Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver` is the most recently updated.

How do I go about chosing which one to use?

Is there an "official" Chrome Selenium plugin? (and given that the main Selenium Nuget package includes a `Chrome` namespace, why do I need a separate driver anyway?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have shared the link with you of the official site so from there you can download selenium webdriver i have also used the same version and its working fine

https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/

I hope  this will help you